# Pythonic way to structure if statement for changing variable values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep

As title says, what's the pythonic way to write the following code?

```
if x == 1:
    myvar = "a string"
elif x == 2:
    myvar = "another string"
elif x == 3:
    myvar = "yet another string"
else:
    raise Exception("arg x must be 1, 2 or 3")
```

It seems a bit clumsy to do the above, and for longer examples, much more time consuming and messy.

Comment: For longer examples, you want to use a dictionary

Comment: This code is perfectly fine and pythonic. Yes, if it got too long youight use a `dict` but this is the best way at this scale IMO

Comment: @roganjosh ...where "longer" is like 3+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a dictionary for this:

```
x = 3 # Then try with 4

outcome_dict = {1: "some string", 2: "another string", 3: "yet another string"}

my_var = outcome_dict.get(x)

if my_var is None:
    raise Exception("arg x must be 1, 2 or 3")

print(my_var)
```

The `dict.get()` method will return `None` if the key is not found. In this example, all of the outcomes need to be manually typed in `outcome_dict` but in practice, dictionaries are easy to create for thousands of key: value pairs in a single line of code e.g. *dictionary comprehensions* or just regular `for` loops.

Comment: You are one a roll. Nice one +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @roganjosh's solution, you can also try using `try` and `except`.

```
dict_values = {1: "some string", 2: "another string", 3: "yet another string"}

# Using for x = 3
x = 3

try:
    print (outcome_dict[x])
except:
    print ("arg x must be 1, 2 or 3")
# yet another string
```

---

```
# Using for x = 4
x = 4

try:
    print (outcome_dict[x])
except:
    print ("arg x must be 1, 2 or 3")
# arg x must be 1, 2 or 3
```

Comment: I like the brevity of this approach as well. +1 It might just be me though, but shouldn't you have `except KeyError` according to PEP8?